# Getting `Fatal: Option "nodekey": invalid character '"' at end of key file` when trying `geth --nodekey /path/file`

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients

I generated a key-pair with `geth account new --keystore`

and now I'm trying to attach it to a light node with `geth --nodekey`,

but I'm getting the error `Fatal: Option "nodekey": invalid character '"' at end of key file`.

The file hasn't been altered and I cannot actually find a `"` on its end.

Instead of simply trying to generate a new one, I'd love to learn what's wrong with this one. Any clues?